# how to clear the buffer of character in C

Tags: c

I am working on a C program that saves input from stdin and saves into an array.
I do some processing with that array and I am wanting to clear the array. I tried malloc and free and memset also. None of them worked. Here is the code

```
while(1)
{
    printf("? ");
    char *line;
    line = (char *) malloc(MAX_BUFFER);
   // char line[MAX_BUFFER];
    if (!fgets(line, MAX_BUFFER , stdin))
         return 0;
    parse(&cmd, line);  // this function prints the string
    free(line);
}
```

parse.c

```
void parse(Command *cmd, char *line)
 {

    char *p = strtok (line, " \n");

    //while loop tokenizes the line into logical parts store them into array called commandsArray
    while (p != NULL)
    {

        // compare the token with output redirection

        if ((!strcmp(p, ">")  || !strcmp(p, ">>") ) &&  ! cmd->isoutputredirected)
        {
             cmd->isoutputredirected = 1;
             cmd->outfileindex  =  cmd->tokenscounter + 1;
             cmd->outputredirectionindex =  cmd->tokenscounter;
        }

        cmd->commandsArray[cmd->tokenscounter++]  = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, " \n");

    }
    //checking if input redirection is found or not

    if (  cmd->isinputredirected == 1)
         cmd->infile =  cmd->commandsArray[ cmd->infileindex];
    else
         cmd->infile = "";

    if (  cmd->isoutputredirected == 1)
        cmd->outfile =  cmd->commandsArray[ cmd->outfileindex];
    else
        cmd->outfile = "";

    if ( cmd->isinputredirected &&  cmd->infile)
        printf("%d: < \'%s\' ",  cmd->commandCounter+1,  cmd->infile );

    int k;

    for ( k = 0; k <  cmd->tokenscounter ; ++k)
    {
         char *token =  cmd->commandsArray[k];

         if(!strcmp(token, cmd->infile)  || !strcmp(token,"<") || !strcmp(token,"<<")    || !strcmp(token, cmd->outfile)  || !strcmp(token,">") ||  !strcmp(token,">>"  )){
             continue;
         }
         else if (!strcmp(token,"|")  || !strcmp(token,">>") || !strcmp(token,">>")  ||  !strcmp(token,"<<") ||   !strcmp(token,">") )
                 printf("%s ", token);
        else
                 printf("\'%s\' ", token);
    }

    if ( cmd->isoutputredirected &&  cmd->outfile)
        printf(" > \'%s\' ",  cmd->outfile );
    printf("\n");
    // clearing the buffer of character and struct
    memset(&cmd, 0, sizeof(cmd));
    memset(line, 0, 1024);
```

When i run I get output like this

```
? hello world
  hello world
? hello world
  hello world hello world
```

My problem here is that the buffer is not cleared.

Comment: `memset(line, 0, MAX_BUFFER)`... No?

Comment: It seems like the question is really about what happens inside `parse`, which you didn't show.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer tried this. did not work.

Comment: @interjay I updated my question with code for parse()

Comment: `sizeof(line)` and `sizeof(cmd)` are the size of pointers, not the things they point to.  Additionally, they are also pointers so you don't want `&` in front. That may not be the only bug - I didn't read your code.

Comment: The problem isn't `line`. It's `cmd`.

Comment: Should be memset(cmd not memset(&cmd

Comment: Should not even be memset, just: *cmd = '\0'

Comment: You didn't show what's inside `parse`. That's required information for a [mcve].

Comment: It's too bad that the `parse` function is too long... you should make a toy example (for example replace it with `puts` or something)

Comment: This code is correct as it is--you are passing parse() the address of cmd and the string the user inputted (assuming it's shorter than MAXBUFFER).  You certainly don't need to memset() line, as fgets() is going to overwrite whatever is in it anyways.  Your bug is pretty clearly in parse(); without seeing your code it's impossible to debug.  But my guess is that you are adding to the end of the string in it instead of starting at the beginning.  If you change your code in parse() to start copying to the address passed instead of the end of that string, you'll likely be good to go.

Comment: @Jabberwock I have added parse function. Could you see if i did any mistake, thanks?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the faulty behavior of your program. Improve your code. Repeat till satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the problem, though the code is fairly opaque.  The line

```
cmd->commandsArray[cmd->tokenscounter++]  = p;
```

is what is storing the contents of line into command.  It stores it at array location cmd->tokenscounter.  But you never zero out cmd->tokenscounter, so after the first call, you have

```
cmd->commandsArray[0] == "hello"
cmd->commandsArray[1] == "world"
cmd->tokenscounter == 2
```

On the second call you write

```
cmd->commandsArray[2] = "hello"
cmd->commandsArray[3] = "world"
cmd->tokenscounter == 4
```

So when you go to print the second time, you print all four values.

Comment: You mean double-quotes `"` not single-quotes `'`

Comment: Sorry--been coding too much in Javascript recently.  Will fix...